# RGB values of UIColor in iOS

Tags: ios, rgb, uicolor

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGreyColor()
```

What are the RGB value of 'light Grey' so I can match it up in my PhotoShop graphics?

Comment: Did you try printing the color? Or getting its RGB values?

Comment: I want the RGB colors.  Exactly.... I guess I could try a screen shot and then match it up in Photoshop.   I didn't think of that.

Comment: I mean programmatically getting the color's RGB values. Have you looked at the UIColor documentation?

Answer (score 2):

its.

> R-170, G-170, B-170

you can check it on xcode also

Comment: Oh yeah they do have it.  OK this question is really amateur, sorry.  I just started getting into Photoshop along with programming.  So I guess I asked it too prematurely without doing some research.  Thanks.

Comment: its ok bro..keep learning..